# how can I print loop info using opt?

Tags: clang, llvm

I am trying to print the natural loop information using the `-loops` pass provided by `opt` but somehow nothing is printed. Example:

```
// loop.c
int foo () {
  int i;
  int j;
  for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    j += 1;
  }
  return j;
}
```

then I ran `clang -S -emit-llvm -c l.c -o l.ll` followed by `opt -loops l.ll` but nothing is printed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

run opt with `-analyze`: `opt -analyze -loops <file.bc>`